# Printing output at every nth time step

Tags: c, printf

I am a bit confused about how to write the code to implement this concept. So please help me out if anyone knows how to work around my problem.

I have a while loop to run a simulation where I want to see the diffusion of a mass of fluid for a time that is given by *t_domain*. The time *t* is incremented in steps of *dt* both of which are variables of the type double, however I want to take snapshots of the diffusion process only at *Del_t* time intervals. What I mean is that if I run my simulation for 1000 seconds where time t is incremented by 0.01 seconds, I want to take the snapshots of the diffusion process every 10 seconds.

Now what I am unable to figure out is the section of the code for the *print densities at every nth time step to a file*. Can someone give suggestions?

```
while(t<t_domain)
  {
    //runs a function to solve the continuity equation and Navier Stokes equation
      density_solve(fdparam_1.N,r,r0,ux0,vy0,fdparam_1.Dt,fdparam_1.diff,fdparam_1.MAXIT);
    //print densities at every nth time step to a file 
    t+=dt
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From your description one could conclude that at least `t` and `dt` are floating point variables. But this is guessing. You might like to add this information to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned that now!!

Answer (score 1):

Write a if statement to check like this :

```
while(t<t_domain)
  {
     //runs a function to solve the continuity equation and Navier Stokes equation      
 density_solve(fdparam_1.N,r,r0,ux0,vy0,fdparam_1.Dt,fdparam_1.diff,fdparam_1.MAXIT);
 if(((int)t*100)%1000==0)
     {
     //print densities at every nth time step to a file
       } 
t+=dt
  }
```

now every time t  is 10's multiple it is printed.

As your time would come in float or double with precision of 0.01 I multiply time by 100 to convert it to a workable integer.now I check if it is divisible by 100*10 i.e, 1000 to check if it is a perfect multiple of 10.To make the long story short.........

```
 only numbers like 10.00 and 20.00 are accepted and not 
 numbers like 10.01 or 10.79
```

Comment: You might like to explain why the code introduces/uses the "magic numbers" `100` and `1000` and how they exactly referr to the OP and to the `10` you already mention.

Comment: Now it's clear in a second, thank you. I however already upvoted. As a side note: For production code this explanation should go as a comment to the code shown.

Comment: @SouravKanta Thanks, I think I got the idea. Now it feels super simple. Don't know why it didn't strike me...my programming skills have become super rusty over a period of 5 years now. Sorry for bothering with such a seemingly trivial question. But thank you guys for patiently answering it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
int times = 23;
while(t<t_domain)
      {
        //runs a function to solve the continuity equation and Navier Stokes equation
          density_solve(fdparam_1.N,r,r0,ux0,vy0,fdparam_1.Dt,fdparam_1.diff,fdparam_1.MAXIT);
        //print densities at every nth time step to a file 
        if(i++%times==0)
        {
            // print every 23th loop round
        } 
        t+=dt
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int iteration = 0;
const int N = 10;

while(t<t_domain)
{
    ...
    if(0 == (iteration++ % N))
    {
        // will printe once every 10 iterations
        printf(...);
    }
}
```